# Is there solution for Windows Server to use MD5 certificate NTP source validation/authentication?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, ntp, md5

Is there a built-in or third party solution for Windows Server to use MD5 certificate NTP source validation/authentication?

If it is built-in, what version of Windows Server and what is the feature called etc.?

(I can't find it so far.)

Recommended third party solutions?

Comment: All supported versions of Windows no longer trust MD5 certificates.  You do understand, that MD5 certificates are not secure, right?  All of the major browsers also do not support them, including the mobile variants, on all mobile platforms.

Comment: Better than nothing, but is there are secure NTP client whether this or something else?
Any help appreciated.  Company has new NTP server and this is what it needs.

Comment: Windows has actively not trusted MD5 certificates for 4 years.  Are you 100% sure, there is no possible way, to generate SHA1 certificate instead?  Even then you are looking at SHA1 certiicates to be blocked by the end of 2017.

Comment: I need to either offer the methods, or tell them it cannot be done (with existing tools).
Or present a better way.
The only thing that might make sense that has occurred to me so far is:  Certificate IPSec (not VPN).

Comment: @HerbM did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, but to be fair, shortly after this posting and the updates above I stopped looking and told management it could not be done with any known settings or features of Windows without changing how the NTP clients connect (e.g., IPSec).  Not what they wanted so they dropped the matter.