# How to use secure NTP authentication from Windows client to a Linux Server?

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, ntp

I have a `NTP Server` running on a Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) box and I also have to  securely serve a bunch of `Windows Server` boxes (2012, 2012 R2 and 2008 R2 mainly). For network equipements and Linux servers I'm using `MD5` keys but I don't know how to do something similar on Windows.

I tried to google that issue but all I could find is this [thread](https://superuser.com/q/1198361/450540).

How can I securely sync the Windows boxes with the `Linux NTP server` ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/740490/ntp-with-authentication-on-windows-system You need an AD domain server, the trust relationship between the AD server will be secure this will insure the SNTP connection is trusted.   (SNTP is Windows NTP)

Comment: OK @Ramhound and what if I don't have an AD or don't want to set one.

Comment: Read the link I provided. You said you had Windows Servers....

Comment: The linked question on Server Fault discusses using the Windows boxes as the SNTP time source. It appears this question is about having the Windows servers get authenticated time from the NTP server running on Linux.

Comment: Yes @TwistyImpersonator I already have a Linux box acting as an NTP server and I want windows clients to sync through it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses a subset of the NTP protocol (SNTP)[https://serverfault.com/questions/740490/ntp-with-authentication-on-windows-system], you won't be able to use the same authentication mechanisms.

Since you can't use Active Directory for authentication, you'll probably have to use a different (third party) NTP client that supports it.

Comment: Okay, any good Open source NTP client to advise?